# How do I search for a specific character at position 0 of strings in a list?

Tags: python

I know how to get the first letter from different items in the list, but i was wondering if using the list.count() function or something you can count the amount of a specific character at character 1 in a list, in my case, the letter g.
because im storing the type and the position in one item to save space and coding, i was wondering if it was possible to count the amount of letter 'g's in a list in the position 1 (or 0, bc python arrays)

I tried using the count() but that didn't work.

edit: okay so I was asked for an exmaple so here's my current code for counting. (for context, I'm making a game for DIT and im trying to count the gold mines to get gold amounts depending on the amounts, and I store the x/y posin the items too, so it would be like g(10-12) or something)

and, no, there are no empty items or strings in this, as the playStuff list is all of the stuff that the player owns frmo the 'board' list

edit3: okay so I'm not very good at explaining, sorry. to deferenciate my question from the other suggestion, I'm trying to count the amount of items in a list that start with a specific letter. g. It has to ignore the rest for the item, and count how many, and set the variable newGold to that amount.
I've tried using the count() function but it didn't work. I've tried so much random code that I came up with but nothing so far has worked.

EDIT4: I am so sorry for being so unreliable I am terrible at explaining. I see what you mean Karl, but I'm going to use this code for other functions in my code but I just need help getting git to work properly. currently,all i want to do is count the amount of letter 'g's there are at character 0 in every item on the list, playerStuff. I've said this multiple times, and the links that you give me are either anot relevant (at least i don't know how to use those to help me) or are just confusing overall.
I'm pretty limited in my python knowledge, i haven't used it for two years, which is why i reached out here to see if anyone could try and help me.
for the list, it's stored in strings, and contain the identifier for what it is and the position of that on the board. eg. g["(10-12)", "w(20-2)"]
so I'm trying to get the first character and check if its g or not.
just the first CHARACTER in each string. i'm not sure if i explained that correctly. please ask if  to explain more
(thank you for helping me!)

and, I believe I understand python well, not super complex stuff, but I know how to use python much better than everyone I know. sorry if I don't understand though, I haven't used python in two years.

```py
    def gold():
        global gold
        gold += newGold
        playerStuff.count(playerStuff[0]) # this is what I'm trying to get to count all of the g's in the list 'playerStuff'
        print("You got " + newGold + "gold!")
```

Comment: With a cleverly-written class, you can do anything with `list.count`, which blindly invokes `__eq__`. But you'll be much better off and learn a lot more from doing it with a `for` loop.

Comment: Please provide an example. And can there be empty strings?

Comment: I meant an example list of strings. Both for clarity of the question and so that we can use it for testing potential solutions.

Comment: The most apparent problem in the code attempt is that you apparently do not understand *how to make the rest of the code use* the result that you get from `playerStuff.count(playerStuff[0])` (i.e., calling that *method* on the string). Methods are a kind of function and what you need to understand is how to communicate information between functions properly. I gave a duplicate link to explain that, but there seem to be many other issues with your overall understanding of Python and programming in general. I strongly advise you to try to follow a Python tutorial first.

Comment: "or something you can count the amount of a specific character at character 1 in a list, in my case, the letter g." - It's not clear what you mean. "character 1" doesn't make any sense already: "character" only means an element of a string, not an element of any other kind of container. We can't see the rest of your code, anyway, so we don't know **what is stored in** the list or **how it is structured**. For example, did you mean that every element of the list is a string? Or that, at least, the first element is a string? Or is it something else?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to count the number of occurrences of the letter 'g' at the first position (index 0) in each item of a list, you can iterate over the list and check the first character of each item. Here's how you can do it:

```py
    # Example list
    my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'orange', 'mango']
    
    # Initialize count
    count = 0
    
    # Iterate over the list
    for item in my_list:
        # Check if the first character of the item is 'g'
        if item[0] == 'g':
            count += 1
    
    # Print the count
    print("Number of items starting with 'g':", count)
```

This code will output the number of items in the list that start with the letter 'g'. You don't need to use list.count() here because you're not counting the occurrences of 'g' within each item, but rather counting the items themselves where 'g' is the first character.

Comment: And the short version: `count = sum(1 for s in my_list if s[0] == 'g')`

Comment: *"If you want to count the number of occurrences of the letter 'g' at the first position (index 0) in each item of a list"* - Why did you repeat the question?

Comment: *"You don't need to use list.count() here because you're not counting the occurrences of 'g' within each item"* - So if they *did* want to count the occurrences of 'g' within each item, you *would* use list.count() for that? How?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and do not try to read the OP's mind.

Comment: I am just trying to check if the first letter of the list is g. i updated the OP so probably read that and then try and answer again. I tried to show more of what i was trying to get ehlp with, but thanks fro helping